Sum of elements of a finite field in terms of a generator of the field
Consider the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Then $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}$ will be cyclic. Let $\alpha$ be a generator of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}$ i.e., $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}=\langle\alpha\rangle$. Is there any way to directly calculate the sum of two elements of the field in terms of power of  $\alpha$? That is can we find $\alpha^{i}+\alpha^{j}$ in terms of power of $\alpha$ without any other information about $\alpha$?

Are you only interested in finite fields of prime order, or also of prime power order?

No way. This is why discrete logarithm tables as well as their inverse tabels and Zech logarithms were invented.

No there is not; the unit group of the finite field $\Bbb{F}_5$ is generated by both $\alpha:=2$ and $\alpha'=3$. But
$$2^2+2^1=2^0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 3^2+3^1=3^3,$$
so there is no way to simplify $\alpha^2+\alpha^1$ for a generator $\alpha$ without knowing which generator it is.

What if we restrict i and j as both even. If we fix i and vary j, can we say exactly when the resultant power of $\alpha$ is even or odd? Or how may times it is even or odd?

That's a different question from the original.

Yes but can you please help me with this one. I am only considering fields of prime order.

You can ask a new question. Feel free to link it to this one for reference.
